# Working IDE for Rails3 on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide, netbeans-6.9

I´m having a hard time configuring NetBeans for Rails3 in Windows. I got a lot of problems, many o then reported even here.

So my question is: which of the following IDEs are best situated for Rails3 in a Windows Box right now:

RubyMine

Komodo IDE

RadRails

Look, i dont want to start a discussion (kinda x vs y). I just want to know from people who already are developing in Rails3 with Windows what is the better choice in the long run.

Thanks!

EDIT

Issues with NetBeans

[Issue 1](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/6430/capturenjk.jpg)

[Issue 2](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/6249/capturevmj.jpg)

Note: Im using RubyMine by now and facing no problems

Comment: Could you detail some of the problems you have in netbeans? I use it all the time and have installed it on multiple machines without a problem.

Comment: I switched from Aptana to NetBeans and I have not had any problems. Please list the issues you have faced.

Comment: Sure guys, i wrote more details above. Thanks for the help.

Comment: FYI netbeans has dropped rails: http://netbeans.org/community/news/show/1507.html

Comment: The jruby team has picked it up again http://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/fdvlc/jruby_team_going_to_adopt_netbeans_ruby_plugin/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using
[RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/).

You can try it for free for 30 days. Before my time with RubyMine, I've used NetBeans for Rails too. But I have to say RubyMine is the money worth.

Comment: Yes Daniel, i see. I´m considering for serious to buy a personal developer license after the 30 days, because i´m really liking this IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Redcar](http://redcareditor.com/). Very beautiful IDE, similar TextMate

Comment: I had never heard of Redcar, a quick once over shows it to be very straight forward with a nice simple UI.  Good find.

Answer (score 2):

When I develop Rails on Windows, I use Aptana RadRails or Aptana Studio (pretty much the same thing).   They are a little bit heavyweight, but I like the Eclipse interface in general.  It often does better at syntax highlighting and autocorrecting than TextMate and has vastly better keyboard shortcuts.  The TextMate/Mac fanboys are probably going to come after me for saying that.  If you have plenty of memory to spare, Aptana is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I use RubyMine, but their Java IDE has a free community edition with a Ruby plugin, which does have of what RubyMine does, FWIW.

Though to be honest, you will probably get a lot of responses saying no IDE... VIM, Emacs etc...

Comment: Hi Chris and thanks for the answer. Right now i´m using RubyMine and i´m liking it. Problem with no IDE is the production time for "noobs" like me. I dont know how to configure tons of stuff to use the editors alone, like plugins and gems necessaries to get stuff done, so maybe it´s not a good idea right now.

Answer (score 1):

Aptana looks good. But I think RadRails supports only Rails 2. Aptana studio 3 Beta has a full fledged Rails 3 interface.

Also Aptana solves many RoR installation issues in Windows (which can get very messy) . So I think aptana is the way to go

Comment: I´m trying RubyMine by now and will take a close look at aptana soon. But like you, I got all my RoR issues solved switching from a more generic IDE (NetBeans) to a more Rails focused like, RubyMine on my case.

Answer (score 1):

I like RubyMine, as it's pretty fast and does a great job.

Comment: That´s it. I´m using it and loving it. Do you know how to open the DOS CONSOLE (not the Rails console) directly from RubyMine?

Comment: The only thing that I can think of is to type in the following in the console:  exit

Answer (score 0):

I wrote up a brief description of some popular editors as a part of my P2PU course.  Scroll to "Choosing a Programmer's Editor" on the [week 1 curriculum](http://alindeman.github.com/p2pu-rubyrails/week1.html).

Comment: Good work mate, but do you have any experience to share about which is the most situed for Rails3 (on windows) right now? Late i will take a close look at Vim and Emcas, because i´m planning to migrate my development ambient to unix (probably Debian or FreeBSD).

Answer (score 0):

Starting with an IDE can definitely get you started, especially one like RubyMine since it's mostly cross platform.

However, learning an editor like Vim or Emacs has other benefits like being able to be completely cross-platform.  More importantly, they're lightweight both in disk space and in memory usage.  While using an IDE might assist in you learning a language (because you get syntax completion, documentation, etc), learning an editor can lead to the kind of power usage that one using an IDE can only dream of (but it will take a while to get to that point on something like Vim or Emacs).

Answer (score 0):

[e-texteditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) would be a good choice.