# Looking for IDE for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide, jruby

I'm about start working on a JRuby (on rails) project with high level of integration with Java code.

I have some experience with Aptana. Are there any other preferred IDEs for JRuby On Rails (coding, testing, running, ...)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16064/what-ide-to-use-for-developing-in-ruby-on-rails-on-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759141/working-ide-for-rails3-on-windows

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59968/best-editor-or-ide-for-ruby

Answer (score 2):

[RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/) of course — get it now while it's cheaper than TextMate.

<sub>Disclaimer: yes, I work for JetBrains.</sub>

Comment: Alas, it's only free for established open-source projects.

Comment: RubyMine is awesome and well worth the money, and I say that as a not-JetBrains employee. :)

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans and Eclipse are good free alternatives. They may require some configuration to play nicely with jruby.